# Decrypt[rsaPrivateKey[],ByteArray[]] returns non-repeatable answers

Tags: cryptography

```
privKey = PrivateKey[<|"Cipher" -> "RSA", "Padding" -> None, 
    "PublicExponent" -> 80239, "PublicModulus" -> 16678327, 
    "PrivateExponent" -> 8124550|>];
(*private exponent was calculated as
    PowerMod[PublicExponent,-1,PublicModulus]*)
pubKey = PublicKey[<|"Cipher" -> "RSA", "Padding" -> None, 
    "PublicExponent" -> 80239, "PublicModulus" -> 16678327|>];

Decrypt[privKey, ByteArray[{1, 0, 0}]] // Normal // BaseForm[#, 16] &
(*unpredictable result*)
Decrypt[privKey, ByteArray[{1, 0, 0}]] // Normal // BaseForm[#, 16] &
(*unpredictable result*)

Decrypt[pubKey, ByteArray[{1, 0, 0}]] // Normal // BaseForm[#, 16] &
(*nice, repeatable result*)
Decrypt[pubKey, ByteArray[{1, 0, 0}]] // Normal // BaseForm[#, 16] &
(*nice, repeatable result*)
```

The above is a simple RSA decryption; I just started playing with the cryptography support in Mma 10.1. I am not concerned with the actual values returned or even whether the PrivateExponent is correct, but I am somewhat surprised that the `Decrypt[privKey, …]` lines would return non-repeatable and ever-changing results. A kernel restart produces a new series of results instead of repeating the most recent one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cautiously and carefully look in Wolfram Research/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Components/Cryptography/EncryptDecrypt.m for the Mathematica source code for Encrypt and Decrypt to attempt to understand exactly why it does what it does. Be very careful that you don't break anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Bill. The trace ends at SystemFiles\Components\Cryptography\Resources\Libraries\OpenSSLLink64.dll, which is loaded by EncryptDecrypt.m. Regrettably, there seems to be no documentation on the contents of the RSA structure built by the glue code in this DLL before it calls into OpenSSL (or libeay32).
This notwithstanding, I still think that in the absence of padding, randomly generated IVs and such, a simple decryption should produce a repeatable result. Perhaps nobody ever tested with `"Padding" -> "None"`?

Comment: Under Details in the documentation for Decrypt it says the second argument is to be a valid encrypted message. Using FullForm on a few example encrypted messages shows these appear to be very different from an arbitrary three byte array that I might make up. I'm not trying to defend them, but it seems that you are passing bad input to a function and puzzled at the output you get. If you could show a similar error when decrypting a valid encrypted message then that would be more interesting.

Comment: The thing is, a ByteArray[] is valid (as long as either it conforms to the padding spec, or `"Padding" -> "None"`, in which case it is the raw encrypted message with length <= length of modulus). The docs for Decrypt have an example, the last one in section "Scope":  

`Decrypt can be passed a ByteArray:`  

The code to which you pointed me, EncryptDecrypt.m, also deals specifically with ByteArray[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `privKey` is not a valid RSA key, so I wouldn't expect `Decrypt` to work properly with it. The formula you've used `PrivateExponent = PowerMod[PublicExponent,-1,PublicModulus]` makes no sense and contradicts the purpose of private key cryptography. Using your formula means anyone who has the public key can easily calculate the private key, then it's not private anymore. The `privKey` you feed into `Decrypt` is now basically a valid `PublicExponent`, a valid `PublicModulus`, and a random `PrivateExponent`. Moreover, the above `privKey` and `pubKey` are not a pair.
`Decrypt` here could throw an error about the key being invalid, but its definitely not supposed to work properly.

Comment: 1/ Hi @Dariia Porechna, and thank you for commenting! I fully agree with your remarks regarding the security of the "private key"; this example was contrived to demonstrate, in the simplest possible way, a particular behaviour, namely the non-repeatability of whatever Decrypt[] does. I do not agree that the private exponent is random, neither in the probabilistic nor in the colloquial sense. As I recall, the private exponent worked perfectly fine for manual encryption/decryption. That is, of course, why I used insecure values -- manual verification. (continued)

Comment: 2/ @Dariia Porechna More to the point, I am of your opinion that bad input need not produce sensible output, although some error checking would be nice. An earlier commenter, @Bill, mentioned that my `ByteArray[{1,0,0}]` was not a valid RSA message; actually, it is valid both as plaintext and as ciphertext, because I specified `Padding->None` and because i made veru sure to remain below the size limit for a single RSA message given my key.

Comment: 3/ @Dariia Porechna All that said, my complaint was the ever-changing result. Unless RSA involves randomness or time-of-day or something of the sort, a simple mathematical algorithm should always produce the same results from the same data. _That_ is what caused my distrust in Mathematica's cryptograpy.

I need to re-run those tests with 12.3 (as soon as I have time, hahaha). But in the meantime, I thank you for your observations; we disagree on details, but I will take the liberty of marking your answer as _the_ answer.

Comment: 4/4 @Dariia Porechna Until I can update the question with new results, I bid you welcome to MMA Stack Exchange; I am happy to say that this place is full of people who are far smarter than I am and friendly to boot, and I hope you will like it here!

Comment: Mathematica's Encypt and Decrypt call OpenSSL internally, so the bytes of the key and data are passed to OpenSSL - I wonder which side causes disruption though.
Note that to reproduce this example in M12 you would need to use at least 512-bit long key because that's now the OpenSSL's hard lower limit.